# SoapUI5.7 + Mule4.4: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path parameter must start with /"

Tags: soap, mule, soapui, anypoint-studio, mule4

I'm checking Mule with SoapUI and face an issue `path parameter must start with /`.

**Error message on Mule**

```
WARN  2022-01-23 00:01:02,491 [http.listener.03 SelectorRunner] org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain: GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path parameter must start with /
    at org.mule.runtime.api.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:25) ~[mule-api-1.4.0-20211227.jar:?]
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.util.DefaultRequestMatcherRegistry.lambda$new$1(DefaultRequestMatcherRegistry.java:69) ~[mule-service-http-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.lambda$newMappingFunction$2(LocalLoadingCache.java:140) ~[caffeine-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2379) ~[caffeine-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2377) ~[caffeine-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2360) ~[caffeine-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108) ~[caffeine-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalLoadingCache.java:54) ~[caffeine-2.8.0.jar:?]
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.util.DefaultRequestMatcherRegistry.find(DefaultRequestMatcherRegistry.java:260) ~[mule-service-http-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.server.HttpListenerRegistry.getRequestHandler(HttpListenerRegistry.java:109) ~[mule-service-http-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.server.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:123) ~[mule-service-http-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:540) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.server.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:99) [mule-service-http-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.mule.service.http.impl.service.server.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:74) [mule-service-http-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:415) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:384) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:348) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279) [grizzly-framework-2.3.36-MULE-024.jar:2.3.36-MULE-024]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:113) [mule-service-scheduler-1.4.1/:?]
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54) [mule-service-scheduler-1.4.1/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
```

**Steps**

1. Find WSDL here (https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?WSDL)
2. [Mule4.4] Create Listener and SOAP Router.
   HTTP Listener config: port = 1081
   SOAP configuration: Wsdl location = (URL in Step 1.)
   [image: Mule message flow]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:apikit-soap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit-soap" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit-soap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit-soap/current/mule-apikit-soap.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="api-httpListenerConfig">
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="1081"/>
    </http:listener-config>
    <apikit-soap:config httpStatusVarName="httpStatus" name="soapkit-config" port="NumberConversionSoap" service="NumberConversion" wsdlLocation="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?WSDL"/>
    <flow name="api-main">
        <http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/NumberConversion/NumberConversionSoap">
            <http:response statusCode="#[attributes.additionalTransportData.statusCode default 200]">
                <http:body>#[payload]</http:body>
                <http:headers>#[attributes.protocolHeaders default {}]</http:headers>
            </http:response>
            <http:error-response statusCode="#[attributes.additionalTransportData.statusCode default 500]">
                <http:body>#[payload]</http:body>
                <http:headers>#[attributes.protocolHeaders default {}]</http:headers>
            </http:error-response>
        </http:listener>
        <apikit-soap:router config-ref="soapkit-config">
            <apikit-soap:attributes><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
              output application/java
              ---
              {
                  headers: attributes.headers,
                  method: attributes.method,
                  queryString: attributes.queryString
            }]]]></apikit-soap:attributes>
        </apikit-soap:router>
    </flow>
    <flow name="NumberToWords:\soapkit-config">
        <ee:transform>
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload>
                    <![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
ns soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope
---
{
    body: {
        soap#Fault: {
            faultcode: "soap:Server",
            faultstring: "Operation [NumberToWords:\soapkit-config] not implemented"
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}]]>
                </ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
    <flow name="NumberToDollars:\soapkit-config">
        <ee:transform>
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload>
                    <![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
ns soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope
---
{
    body: {
        soap#Fault: {
            faultcode: "soap:Server",
            faultstring: "Operation [NumberToDollars:\soapkit-config] not implemented"
        }
    } write "application/xml"
}]]>
                </ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

3. [SoapUI5.7] Create a new SOAP API with the URL in Step 1. Then create a new request (https://0.0.0.0:1081/NumberConversion/NumberConversionSoap) and run it. The message at the bottom says "failed to respond"
   [image: SoapUI5.7 request failure]
4. [Mule4.4] See the message.

**Notes**

I confirm Listener's Path starts with "/".
[image: Mule Listener configuration]

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. For Mule flows and configurations paste the text XML

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I added the XML (even though I didn't edit this XML directly).

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning not an error. It is most likely harmless. Ensure you are using the last version of Studio and cumulative patches for Mule 4.4. There is something strange in the log though. It looks to be executing an HTTP service for Mule 4.3 (`mule-service-http-1.6.3`) which is not a right version for Mule 4. May be the project is being executed in Mule 4.3? Check the log when the application is starting and the run configuration to be sure.

Comment: SoapUI doesn't get a response, so there should be an issue. I downloaded Anypoint Studio and Mule a few days ago, so it should be the latest version. I also check `MULE_HOME is set to /Applications/AnypointStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.4.4.0.ee_7.11.0.202201052152/mule` and `Version: 4.4.0-20211227 Build: 6f6c60e6` in the console

Comment: Which version of Studio? Last one is 7.11.1. ensure you downloaded that one and then check for updates.

Comment: This is Anypoint Studio info: "Version: 7.11.1 Build Id: 202201060126". I literally downloaded Anypoint Studio and Mule from here (https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/dl/studio) a few days ago.

Comment: I downloaded and upgraded the same version of Studio and the same version of the Mule runtime (`org.mule.tooling.server.4.4.0.ee_7.11.0.202201052152`). The HTTP service it contains seems the right version but the library jar inside is 1.6.3. Not sure if it is an issue or expected. The warning seems probably a bug. Do you see any other messages in the log?

Comment: I have verified that the version is the correct one and the version numbers are as expected. It is probably a bug which has been present in previous versions.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I somehow failed to make the same message, so couldn't update you. Should I report this as an issue on Github?

Comment: Yes, but Mule has a Jira project to report bugs.